# Using Texmaker, I want to lock the PDF file created so others cannot copy text or print the file

Tags: pdf, latex, miktex, texmaker

I'm creating PDFs using Texmaker. I would like to create some of the PDF files so that when I give the PDF to others, they are not able to print the file or to copy the text. I know I can do this with some PDF creator applications, but can I do that from some command like program I have with Latex, MikTex and TexMaker?

Comment: Waste of our time, and probably of yours, too. All they need is a thing called a "typist".

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't be effective anyway. There are bits in the pdf format that purport to forbid the user from doing this, but they are really just suggestions that the reader application may or may not act on. There is nothing to stop a user from removing the code that inspects the bits from a free/libre PDF reader, or just to run a tool over the file to remove the restrictions.